# custom kernel for secure system

Tags: kernel, apache2, compiling, mysql, gammu

I am pretty new to the linux community and I've started learning it for last few months.

After learning the basics of commands and system architecture im now trying to learn the grass root level operations in Linux. I am trying to compile my own custom kernel as per certain guidelines that I have set for my system. I need to create a minimalistic kernel which i can give to a user with  minimal knowledge of Linux and can carry out basic tasks with minimum guidance. My basic requirement on the system is to run Gammu server, PHP, MySQL and Apache.

I need to know what the basic dependencies are in kernel compilations which I can remove during compilation. I want  to 'restrict' the user to using services required for the running of the above mentioned programs only. The other functionalities provided by the user shall be restricted at kernel level.

However my short knowledge of the dependencies of these programs does not allow me to choose which features can be disabled during kernel compilation. I am using a Linux stable 3.19.3 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the user to those services isn't the sort of thing you do at the kernel level.

If you want to prevent the user from running programs besides PHP &c, the easiest way is don't have those programs on your system.